# How to ignore trailing space in search string entered into search input box?

Tags: phpstorm

Working in PhpStorm 2023.1 if there is way making search(in 1 file or in whole project) to ignore trailing space in search string entered into search input box ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sadly, it is not configurable. For some corner cases during paste, you may enable "ide.find.field.trims.pasted.text" Registry (Help > Find Action > Registry) option. Also (not "Find in Files" but pretty close):
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-335902/Search-Everywhere-Files-tab-should-ignore-trailing-spaces